# What does caret symbol do in string formatting?

Tags: python, string-formatting, text-alignment

I saw this code somewhere, which writes:

```
print("{:-^16}".format("TEXT"))
```

The output is:

```
------TEXT------
```

I understand what the `{}` brackets do, but what does the `-^16` mean? I tried searching online but couldn't find anything.

Comment: - is the fill character, ^ says align in center and 16 is the width.

Answer (score 2):

Braces are used as placeholders for the formatted string.

- 16 is for the size of the string => 16 characters
- ^ center aligns the result (within the available space)

You can find more information here:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp